# iOS 4.2 - SDWebImage

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdwebimage

I am not able to use  SDWebImage on my ios 4.2 app,the current  SDWebImage library is for ios5.0 ARC i think.

Please help is there any version to support iOS 4.2[image]

Comment: If i remember correctly, SDWebImage has non-ARC version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SDWebImage GitHub](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/), "**you may choose the non ARC target if you want to support iOS <3**". So deployment target is not the problem at all.

Comment: yes i can see it, but i am not sure how to add SDWEbimage non arc version inside Xcode 3.2.5 version.Thanks for the reply

Comment: Are you sure you are using the non-ARC version?

Comment: pls refer the image i have enclosed now, the image shows how to include the non arc version on xocde 4.3.1 but i am not sure how to include the non arc version on my xocde which is 3.2.5 version.pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, make sure you added "SDWebImage", not "SDWebImage ARC". Then when you add to the "Link Binaries With Libraries" make sure you add "libSDWebImage.a" not "libSDWebImageARC.a"